# How to remove item in a forEach loop without stopping the traverse

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, lodash

I'm trying to remove items from a list if a condition is applied.

```
var my_list = [
{ 'a': 1, 'b': 2 },
{ 'a': 3, 'b': 4 }
];

my_list.forEach(function (item){

  if (item.a == '1') {

      // Side note : I'm using Lodash to remove the item

      _.pull(my_list, item);

  }

});

// The above forEach runs once, instead of twice.
```

**The problem is that** when I remove the item from the list, the `Foreach` loop skips 1 step and doesn't traverse other items (Obviously because I'm mutating the original array).

**My goal** is to get a list like the original array but excluding all removed items.

How am I supposed to tackle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use lodash `_.clone`

```
var my_list = [
{ 'a': 1, 'b': 2 },
{ 'a': 3, 'b': 4 }
];

_.clone(my_list).forEach(function (item){

  if (item.a == '1') {

      // Side note : I'm using Lodash to remove the item

      _.pull(my_list, item);

  }

});
```

You can also use `_.filter` method - i think it will be better solution.

```
var filteredMyList= _.filter(my_list, function(obj){
    return obj.a != 1 
});
```

Comment: Nice one..! Not sure why I didn't think of this lol. Clean and simple

Answer (score 1):

Do it in reverse order:

```js
for (var i = my_list.length; i >= 0; i--) {
    //removing an item will not disturb the count
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a simple `for loop`, then all you need to remember is to offset the `index` after you `splice`.

```js
var my_list = [
    { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 },
    { 'a': 3, 'b': 4 }
];
//Remove in standard for loop
for (var index = 0; index < my_list.length; index++) {
    var item = my_list[index];
    if (item.a == 1) {
        //Remove element
        my_list.splice(index, 1);
        //Offset index
        index--;
    }
}
console.log(my_list);
```

**EDIT**

Brainfart.. This is what [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is for.

```js
var my_list = [
    { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 },
    { 'a': 3, 'b': 4 }
];
var my_list = my_list
    .filter(function myFilterFunction(item) {
    return item.a != 1;
});
console.log(my_list);
```

Answer (score 1):

If your intention is just to remove items from the list then lodash provides the [**remove**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#remove) function:

```
_.remove(my_list, {a: 1});
```

This wil mutate `my_list`. If you want a new list then use [**reject**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#reject):

```
let new_list = _.reject(my_list, {a: 1});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using lodash and the only thing you are using the forEach loop for is filtering why not use lodash filter method?

```
var my_list = [
    { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 },
    { 'a': 3, 'b': 4 }
];

var my_filtered_list = _.filter(my_list, function(o){
    return o.a != 1 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this a classic use of "filter"? No need to use a loop (and these days you probably shouldn't unless you have a very specific reason to...functional and all that).

```
var my_list = [
{ 'a': 1, 'b': 2 },
{ 'a': 3, 'b': 4 }
];

my_list = my_list.filter ( item => { return item.a !== '1' } );
```

When filter returns false, that item won't be in the new list.